# Ruby - undefined method push' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

`test = network_sg.properties` is a JSON. And I want to append a hash into the JSON `securityRules[]` array.

I tried `test[:securityRules].push(new_rule)`  but I get the error `undefined method push' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Any idea how it can be resovled?

```
NETWORK_SG = Azure::Armrest::Network::NetworkSecurityGroupService.new(conf)
network_sg = NETWORK_SG.get('testing_123', rg)
test = network_sg.properties

puts test

{
  "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
  "resourceGuid": "test",
  "securityRules": [
    {
      "name": "SSH",
      "id": "SSH",
      "etag": "18",
      "type": "Microsoft/securityRules",
      "properties": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to append the following hash to `securityRules[]` array.

```
new_rule = {
  :name => 'rule_2',
  :properties => {
    :protocol          => 'TCP',
    :sourceAddressPrefix => '*',
    :destinationAddressPrefix => '*',
    :access => 'Allow',
    :destinationPortRange => '22',
    :sourcePortRange => '*',
    :priority => '301',
    :direction => 'Inbound',
  }
}

test[:securityRules].push(new_rule)
```

Comment: Why are you using versions of Ruby on Rails that have not been maintained for years and have open, unpatched security vulnerabilities? Also, why are you using two different versions of Ruby on Rails in the same piece of code?

Comment: Can you run `test.keys`, and paste the output here?

Answer (score 1):

The `test` Ruby hash contains `String` keys, not symbols. If you access `test` using the symbol `:securityRules` as key you'll get `nil` because that key doesn't exist.

Use a string instead:

```rb
test["securityRules"].push(new_rule)
```

Comment: Its not appending for some reason. No Error message either.

Comment: @R0bert2 It appears `test` is a `String`, given the output, as ruby would never output Hash keys in that fashion. Try `test = JSON.parse(network_sg.properties)` then `test["securityRules"].push(new_rule)`

Comment: That's a good point @engineersmnky. But I think that if it were a string then trying to access it with `test[:securityRules]` would raise a `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`.

Comment: I agree with you that Ruby wouldn't print a Hash like that. That's raw JSON, and I missed it. So you might be onto something here.